# How to move the file in server

Tags: php, html

From this code will be working on local while uploading server file is not moving for this folder,i have FTP access now what will do

```
require_once('config/config.php');
if (isset($_FILES['file'])){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"/img/user-album/original-photo/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
$filename =$_FILES['file']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$original_file =md5($filename).time().rand(10,1000).'-'.$extension;

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO useralbum(photo) VALUES('$original_file')");
if($sql){
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
else{
    echo "ERROR".mysql_error();
}
}
```

Comment: check the folder permission

Comment: File permission is there ,but i don't know y its not moving

Comment: check if the file exists

Comment: No,i truncate the table and folder but not moving

Comment: Did you read the documentation to `move_uploaded_file`? What does `move_uploaded_file` return? Is `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` a valid file?